# Difference in behavior between 2 aliased cds in unix shell

Tags: unix, cd, tcsh

I connect to a remote computer thru VNC and use Konsole for my work. Konsole is version 2.3.3 using KDE 4.3.4. I have these two aliases:

```
alias ll  'ls -haltr; pwd'
alias cd  'cd \!*; ll'
```

which I observed to have the following behavior:

1. When path exists, it will `cd` to it and also do the `ll` alias
2. When path doesn't exist, it will simply say the path doesn't exist and won't do the `ll` anymore

Example:

Path exists

```
[10] % cd foo
total 14K
-rw-r-----  1 user group   913 Jun  3  2014 readme
-rw-r-----  1 user group  1.2K Dec  3  2020 report.txt
drwxr-x---  2 user group  4.0K Jan 12 17:50 ./
drwx------ 77 user group  8.0K Jun 24 11:57 ../
/home/user/foo    
[11] %
```

Path doesn't exist

```
[10] % cd nowhere
nowhere: No such file or directory.
[11] %
```

Now our department has transferred to another division and we've just started to connect remotely thru Exceed TurboX. I still use Konsole but the version is now 2.10.5 using KDE 4.10.5. I copied over the same two aliases, but I'm now observing a different behavior:

1. When path exists, it will `cd` to it and also do the `ll` alias (basically same as #1 above)
2. When path doesn't exist, it will attempt to `cd` *AND* still do the `ll` (**different** as #2 above)

So for #2, here's how it looks like:

```
[10] % cd nowhere
nowhere: No such file or directory.
total 120K
-rw-r-----  1 user group   272 Jan  6  2021 .cshrc
-rw-r-----  1 user group  1.2K Jan  6  2021 .alias
drwxr-x---  2 user group  4.0K Jan 12 17:50 ./
drwx------ 77 user group  8.0K Jun 24 11:57 ../
/home/user
[11] %
```

I would like to know how to get behavior #2 of the previous working environment to this current working environment.

I've added the information on the Konsole and KDE versions because if the behavior is due to the version and there's no workaround, then I'll just be sad for the rest of my life working in this new remote desktop env. ^_^

I'm currently exploring a "check first if the path exists before doing `ll`" but to no avail. :'(

Edit:
The shell I'm using is `tcsh`
`% printenv SHELL` in both environments showed `/bin/tcsh`
And in addition:

Old environment

```
% echo $version
tcsh 6.17.00 (Astron) 2009-07-10 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec
```

New environment

```
% echo $version
3
```

Comment: `Konsole is version 2.3.3 using KDE 4.3.` that information is unrelated really. What is important is what _shell_ (bash? dash? zsh? fish?) are you running _inside_ the terminal program (konsole) that is used to _view_ (_only_ view) the output of the shell.

Comment: Maybe the shell is `csh` as there is `/home/user/.cshrc`. The behavior may depend on the version of `csh` and the code in `.cshrc` or `.alias` and system wide startup files, e.g. `/etc/csh.cshrc` or `/etc/csh.login`. I have nearly no experience with `csh`; maybe there is an option to stop the execution of an alias if a command reports an error. (similar to `set -e` in `sh` or `bash`) I think the main issue is that you should use conditional execution `cd ... && ll` instead of sequential execution `cd ... ; ll`

Comment: ```printenv SHELL``` in both environments showed me ```/bin/tcsh```, so I thought it could not be the one affecting the difference at all.

Comment: @Bodo the inexperienced shell user in me never knew about the ```&&``` until now. It is now working perfectly. Could you make your post as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @renvill Please [edit] your question and add the information about `tcsh` there. Please also show the output of `echo $version` in both environments. BTW: It might not be a good idea to automatically run `ll` after `cd` if the directory contains many files, e.g. `cd /usr/bin`

Comment: Obviously the variable `version` is completle different in the new environment. It doesn't show the expected information. Maybe a shell startup script uses the same variable name and overwrites the information about the shell with the value `3`. Is there any difference in the files `/home/user/.cshrc`, `/etc/csh.cshrc` or `/etc/csh.login`? (The names of the system wide startup files might differ.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information in the question is still not sufficient to find out **why** `tcsh` behaves differently in the two working environments.

The alias defines a sequence of commands (`cd` followed by `ll`) without any condition.

```
alias cd  'cd \!*; ll'
```

On one system the execution of the alias seems to stop if the `cd` command reports an error for currently unknown reasons.

The correct way to prevent the execution of `ll` after a failed `cd` command would be the conditional execution of the `ll` command, e.g.

```
alias cd  'cd \!* && ll'
```

Comment: Just to add, today I also noticed that the simple command ```ls -1d``` isn't correct in the new system. In the old one, I can correctly see just the folders. In the new one, it's still showing ALL files. I looked at ```/etc/csh.cshrc``` and nothing seems 'unusual' (or I might have missed a specific line that can explain this odd behavior). Even the script that is called when I enter a workspace in the new system is just filled with setting environment variables.

Comment: If you want to solve your problem regarding `ls -1d`, please write a new question, show the complete command you use, the actual output you get and the expected output. In the old environment, also show the output of `ls -1F`.

Answer (score 0):

The decade long advice is: do not use aliases, use functions.

```
ll() { ls -haltr "$@" && pwd; }
cd() { cd "$@" && ll; }
```